# await this.ShowMessageAsync is not working in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have one little issue for await this.ShowMessageAsync() method. I googled a lot for my problem, but no success yet.

I am getting error "; expected" for below code

```
private void removeGameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Task<MessageDialogResult> result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Hi", "Message", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
     if(result.Result == MessageDialogResult.Negative)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("No");
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("yes");
     }
}
```

I am getting error with "this". If I didn't use await then it works fine, But then I have no idea to get the result from Message Dialogue.

I installed 2 3 times Microsoft.Bcl.Async as well from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

I am really stuck with this. So please help me to find the solution. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Mark your method as async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare as async. As it looks like an event handler you should create a new method to hold the logic.

```
private async void removeGameButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await DoWork();
}

private async Task DoWork()
{
     Task<MessageDialogResult> result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Hi", "Message", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
     if(result.Result == MessageDialogResult.Negative)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("No");
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("yes");
     }
}
```

One reason for this is exceptions: if your asynchronous method generates an exception declaring the method with `Task` in its signature enables the exception to be contained within the Task object. For example:

```
Task myWork = null;
try 
{
   myWork = DoWork();
   await myWork; //await the Task then an exception occurs
}
catch(SomeException e)
{
   //now you can get at the exception in myWork.Exception
}
```

If you do this then the exception is contained within the `myWork` `Task` object such as via myWork.Exception, which contains the aggregate exception (list of exceptions is possible due to nested await expressions). If you declare methods purely as `async void` then if an error occurs you will end up with an [unobserved exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can handle these at the application level using an event handler setting them to observed.  You can also control whether or not you see these unobserved exceptions using configuration.

```
<configuration> 
   <runtime> 
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
   </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

By default enabled is set to false.

Comment: No problem, do consider exceptions in this context :)

Comment: Really Its very helpful. Thanks Jaycee. I think you have gone very deep into this. :) Thanks Again for your help and the description :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `async` with your method:

```
if ((await this.ShowMessageAsync("Hi", "Message", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative)) == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yesssss");
} 
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Nooooooo");
}
```